# Eclipse and PHP: directories in project's root

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Galileo for PHP Developers and when I create new, empty project I have 3 folders inside:

```
JavaScript Resources
PHP Include Path
PHP Language Library
```

Does Eclipse make copy of PHP for every project? And more important: can I hide it from my project navigator tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong, they are not folders, they are just references, which are defined within the project properties and pdt manages for you. Just look into the folder with your prefered file manager and you will not find folders with this names. So no, eclipse doesnt copy php.
And no, you cant hide them from the php navigator view. There is no obvious reason to hide them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the arrow in the Top Right corner of the PHP Explorer and select "Filters" you CAN exclude them from the view. Select "Libraries from external" and "Libraries in project". Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to hide the JavaScript Resources folder.